# Android : Update other apps from own App

Tags: android, updates

Is it possible to update other installed apps from my own app.
Actually what I want to do is, I want to develop an app that checks for the installed apps on the deice, then checks if there are any updates available for those apps and id there are any, it will update them.

to check whether there is an update available for a particular app, I found out a third party API  click herehttps://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-market-api/-F2QfvGt1nU

So, now is it possibel to update the apps programatically from my app??

Comment: Detection might be possible, asking Play Store app to update is another thing . . . . wait! there is already Play Store App for that isn't there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to work with unsupported API that will for sure break anytime soon, I suggest to do the following:

Check the user installed apps and their versions:

> Use PackageManager and getPackageInfo() to get a PackageInfo object
>   for the specific application, identified by its package (e.g.,
>   com.commonsware.mygreatapp). The versionCode and versionName fields on
>   the PackageInfo will have the information you seek.

Then compare it with latest version of the API:

**EDIT:**
Send the package name to the API: dev.appaware.com/1/doc/examples/example3.php and analyse this line "version": "2.4.0.263535", if this number is different from the version on phone, take the user to Google Play page.

This will be a total duplicate of already existing features...

Comment: Waza_be: "Then compare it with latest version of the API" could you please elaborate?

Comment: Send the package name to the API: http://dev.appaware.com/1/doc/examples/example3.php and analyse this line "version": "2.4.0.263535", if this number is different from the version on phone, take the user to Google Play page.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Play Store app already does this for every app from the play store and I do not believe there is any publicly available API provided by Android to do this in your own app.